# An implementation of solve_ivp (ODE solver)

Tags: python, scipy

This is my first post on stack overflow. So I came across this example of solve_ivp solver in SciPy's documentation. The problem being solved is the following:

*Cannon fired upward with terminal event upon impact. The terminal and direction fields of an event are applied by monkey patching a function. Here y[0] is position and y[1] is velocity. The projectile starts at position 0 with velocity +10. Note that the integration never reaches t=100 because the event is terminal.*

The code in the documentation is the following:

```
>>> def upward_cannon(t, y): return [y[1], -0.5]
>>> def hit_ground(t, y): return y[0]
>>> hit_ground.terminal = True
>>> hit_ground.direction = -1
>>> sol = solve_ivp(upward_cannon, [0, 100], [0, 10], events=hit_ground)
>>> print(sol.t_events)
[array([40.])]
>>> print(sol.t)
[0.00000000e+00 9.99900010e-05 1.09989001e-03 1.10988901e-02
 1.11088891e-01 1.11098890e+00 1.11099890e+01 4.00000000e+01]
```

I have used this solver for solving other differential equations. Further, I understand the usage **terminal** and **direction** fields. But for this example only, I am not able to understand how the function **upward_cannon()** is working by using `return [y[1],-0.5]`.The output corresponding to `print(sol.y)` is the following:

```
[[ 0.00000000e+00  9.99897510e-04  1.09985977e-02  1.10958105e-01
   1.10780373e+00  1.08013149e+01  8.02419261e+01 -1.42108547e-14]
 [ 1.00000000e+01  9.99995000e+00  9.99945005e+00  9.99445055e+00
   9.94445555e+00  9.44450555e+00  4.44500550e+00 -1.00000000e+01]]
```

Since there is no underlying differential equation mentioned in the code, how is the solver producing the above values for `y`? I know `return [y[1],-0.5]` is doing something but I am not able to explain what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> Since there is no underlying differential equation mentioned in the code...

It is not explicitly mentioned, but in fact, there is a differential equation.  Let h(t) be the height of the cannonball.  The differential equation is

```
h''(t) = -0.5
```

That is, the acceleration is constant and in the downward direction.  This is [Newton's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), with the assumption of constant gravitational force.  The example assumes that the ratio of the gravitational constant and the mass is 0.5.

The initial conditions are

```
h(0) = 0,  h'(0) = 10
```

The equation h''(t) = -0.5 is a (trivial!) second order differential equation.  We could solve it with plain old definite integration, but for the sake of the example, we use an ODE solver.  To use `solve_ivp` (or any of the other ODE solvers in SciPy), we must convert the second order DE to a system of first order equations.  Let y0(t) = h(t) and y1(t) = h'(t).  Then

```
y0'(t) = h'(t) = y1(t)
y1'(t) = h''(t) = -0.5
```

That is the system that is implemented in

```
def upward_cannon(t, y):
    return [y[1], -0.5]
```

Comment: `y[1]` holds the value of `y1(t)`.  Its value is the derivative of `y0(t)`.  `solve_ivp` can only solve a *system of first order differential equations*.  The function that you implement returns the first order derivatives.